# Finite field extensions of degree 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $\mathbb{Q}\leq K$ be a field extension of degree 2.
Show that there exists $\psi\in K$ such that $K = \mathbb{Q}[\psi]$ and $\psi^{2}$ is a square free integer.

Since $\mathbb{Q}\leq K$ is a finite field extension, then we know that $\mathbb{Q}\leq K$ is indeed algebraic.

Now, I know that $K$ is generated by $\{1,\psi\}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ for $1,\psi\in K$.

Since the extension is finite, we also have that $\psi$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, then we have a minimum polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Q}[]$ such that $f(\psi)=0\in K$.

Then, $\deg(f)=2$, but now I'm unsure how to proceed further.

Comment: Try completing the square.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elementary field theory, field extensions of the rationals of degree 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124230/elementary-field-theory-field-extensions-of-the-rationals-of-degree-2) or that? [Field extension of $\mathbb Q$ of degree 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364721)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying by denominators, if necessary, we get $f \in \Bbb Z[X]:  f(X)=aX^2+bX+c$.  Then the quadratic formula tells us the roots of $f$ are:

$$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$

Thus, $K= \Bbb Q\left [\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \right ]$.  Moreover, $b^2-4ac$ cannot itself be a square, or $\Bbb Q = K$, which we know is not the case.

Therefore, $b^2-4ac=m^2n$ where $n$ is square-free, and $K=\Bbb Q [\sqrt n ]$.